# Jquery timepickr showing lots of {label:s} fields instead of regular output

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I'm trying to integrate [jquery-timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/#s-intro) on my website, but no matter what version I download (trunk, latest final, latest alpha, the one from the demo site), I keep having the same problem:

I applied the time picker with the default options:

```
$("#MyTimeField").timepickr();
```

When I click on the field I bound the timepicker to, I get a
vertical row of buttons saying "{label:s}". When clicking one of
these buttons , the following text appears in the input field:
"{h:02.d}:{m:02.d}".

My guess was that it might be some problem with the prerequisites,
so I made sure that jquery.strings are jquery.utils are installed,
tried various different versions of your plugin, also different
jquery-ui versions, but still no luck.

Any  hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fields are not parsed, could be an event not firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jquery.validate plugin from [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)? The latest jquery.timepickr should have fixed it. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/issues/detail?id=15) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the strings are not being replaced - do you have link or code example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, but at least at first at first glance I had a hard time understanding the source code for the plugin. Regarding code: My code is simply $("#MyTimeField").timepickr();
, the code to the plugin is available at the site I linked in my posting: http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/#s-intro

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has not been solved... and maybe it's too late now... but I wanted to suggest that if you're still stuck, try another picker, such as the [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/).  I hope it will meet your needs!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Andrew. The plugin looks nice, but I prefer jqurey-timepickr's button layout since it requires less space on the screen. That's important for me since I am planning to use this for a smartphone-friendly website.

Comment: Adrian, you can change the font-size in the CSS file to result in a smaller picker, which might fit your size requirements.  I have noticed that some very small or very large font sizes do have a negative impact on the layout, but with very little tweaking it is usually possible to make drastic changes to the picker's size.  If you decide to give it a shot, and have any specific problems, shoot me a message and I'll be happy to try to help make it work.